# Excel VBA SQL Query on not saved Workbook

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook with some macros. With one macro I open another existing workbook (which already contains some data) and add some rows to it. Then, using another macro (*uebergebene_wo*), I make a SQL query on that workbook, but the query only finds rows that are in the workbook on disk. None of the added rows. If I save the workbook after adding the rows, all the data is found.
When I add the rows to the workbook that the macro is in, I don't need to save the workbook first.
What can I do to get the data from the external workbook without saving?

These are the relevant parts of the macro:

```
Dim conn As Object 'SQL-Connection
' Path to the files
Public Const strReportDir As String = "Q:\Reporting\KPIs\"
' Name of the raw-data-file
Public Const strBewegRoh As String = "Bewegung Rohdaten.xlsx"

Function connect_sql(strWbPath As String)
    'Connect to the Data Source
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    With conn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & strWbPath & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
        .Open
    End With
End Function

Sub uebergebene_wo()
' Fragt die Daten für Übergebenw WO ab.

    Dim rs As Object 'RecordSet
    Dim sql As String
    Dim start_row As Integer: start_row = 1
    Dim start_col As Integer: start_col = 1
    Dim iCol As Integer

    connect_sql (strReportDir & strBewegRoh) ' Verbindung herstellen
    
    'write SQL
    sql = "Select * from [WO-Bewegung Rohdaten$] Where `Datum Übergabe` BETWEEN 45021 AND 767010"
    
    'run SQL
    Set rs = conn.Execute(sql) 'delete data from previous runs in worksheet "Results" Worksheets("Results").Cells(start_row, start_col).CurrentRegion.Clear
    
    Set wksBewegResults = Workbooks(strBewegRoh).Worksheets("Results")
    'insert header row worksheet "Results" (only if HDR=YES)
    For iCols = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        wksBewegResults.Cells(start_row, start_col + iCols).Value = _
            rs.Fields(iCols).Name
    Next
    
    'paste result of sql to worksheet "Results"
    wksBewegResults.Cells(start_row + 1, start_col).CopyFromRecordset rs
    
    'clean up and free memory
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Reading from the workbook **on its path** it is not any method to make it knowing what you modified in computer RAM, if not saving. But you can try a workaround: 1. Open the workbook and add the necessary rows. 2. `SaveCopyAs` the workbook name plus a suffix, let us say, "temp".  3.  Run the query on this saved As Copy one. 4. `Kill` it and close the workbook you initially open, without save it.

Comment: I'm doing something like that now, but saving takes extra time, so I wanted to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

*What can I do to get the data from the external workbook without saving?*

*Ans: Probably nothing*

However, if your idea is to obtain the information in those workbooks, it might be a good idea to save all the Excel workbooks with code:

```
Sub SaveAllWorkbooks()
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    For Each wbk In Excel.Workbooks
        wbk.Save
    Next
End Sub
```

Consider adding the code on the line below `Sub uebergebene_wo()`
here, like this:

```
Sub uebergebene_wo()
SaveAllWorkbooks
' Fragt die Daten für Übergebenw WO ab.
```

Comment: Okay, I'm doing something like that now. But why isn't it necessary, when the sheet is in the same workbook where the marco is?

Comment: @romeofox  - you can use `ThisWorkbook.Save`, if it 1 sheet only, and it is in that specific workbook, where the code is located. Actually, this one is preferred, as the other one will save every opened Excel worksheet on your PC.